# When two locationManager objects call requestLocationUpdates(...)?

Tags: android, location, locationmanager

The code is like this :

```
private LocationManager locationManager1;
private LocationManager locationManager2;    
......
locationManager1 =(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager2 =(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    
....
locationManager1.requestLocationUpdates("GPS",30000, 0, LbsClient2ServerDemo.this);

locationManager2.requestLocationUpdates("GPS",0, 0, LbsClient2ServerDemo.this);    
......
```

When two  locationManager  objects call `requestLocationUpdates(...)` ,
locationManager1 and locationManager2  have the GPS providers.

The  locationManager1 object is searching the satellites now , but the locationManager2 is coming , will the locationManager2.requestLocationUpdates() interrupt the locationManager1 ? Maybe will it cause the GPS location much more slowly?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create two objects of **LocationManager**.

Use this way to get all available providers and get fixes from them, and the fixes returned in `onLocationChanged()` will be the better which **LocationManager** can get.

```
List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
for (String provider : providers) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);
}
```